# Definition of Simple Predictable Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am reading Protter's book "Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations". He (page 51) defines $H$ to be a simple predictable processes if it has a representation 
$$H_t=H_0\mathbf1_{\{0\}}+\sum_{i=1}^nH_i\mathbf1_{(T_i,T_{i+1}]}(t)$$
where $0=T_1\le \dots\le T_n<\infty$ are stopping times and $H_i\in\mathcal{F}_{T_i}$ with $|H_i|<\infty$ a.s. The collection of all such processes is denoted with **S**.

And then he imposes the uniform convergence (in $(t,\omega)$) topology on the space **S**. What makes me confused is that according to this definition, it seems that the uniform metric is not really well-defined as it can be $\infty$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Usually, one assumes $H_i \in L^{\infty}$ and then the (uniform) norm is well-defined.

Comment: @saz so does that mean the definition on protter is inaccurate?

Comment: I would say so. Another possibility: Allow that the norm takes values in $[0,\infty]$. In general that doesn't make any trouble...

Comment: It seems to me that Protter **does not** assume simple processes are uniformly bounded. See, e.g. his use of $\mathbf{S}$ versus $\mathbf{bS}$ in Theorem 20.

Comment: I think that @saz is right. The simple predictable processes have to be assumed uniformly bounded. A reference that I consider very useful is  *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion*  from Daniel Revuz and Marc Yor at page 138, after definition 2.3